# Adding additional text to Spanned String gets rid of my Bold text.

Tags: java, android, html, android-edittext, spannablestring

I'm taking user input and adding that text as bold text in an edittext box on an alert dialog. The problem is, when the user adds more text a second or third or fourth time (etc), the previous bolded text goes away and only the latest bolded text shows. Help is appreciated, thank you.

Here is my code:

```
newField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            storyText = story.getText().toString();


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Title");

            // Set up the input
            final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
            input.setHint("Ex: Noun, Verb, Color, etc");
            // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets
            // the input as a password, and will mask the text
            builder.setView(input);

            // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("Add Field",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            int y;
                            for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                            {
                                field[i] = "";
                            }
                            for(y = 0; y < 200; y++)
                            {
                                if(field[y].equals(""))
                                {
                                    field[y] = input.getText().toString();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }


                            storyText = storyText + " " + "<b>" + field[y] + "</b>" + " ";
                            storyText.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
                            spanned = Html.fromHtml(storyText);
                            story.setText(spanned);

                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Field Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            builder.show();


        }
    });
```

Comment: @Phil no, it is just a string, I got it from my edittext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the String rather than the SpannableString from the TextView, so you are losing your formatting.

Currently you have something like:

```
String storyText = story.getText().toString();
// ...
storyText = storyText + " " + "<b>" + field[y] + "</b>" + " ";
storyText.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
spanned = Html.fromHtml(storyText);
story.setText(spanned);
```

But you might want to try something like:

```
SpannableString spannedStoryText = new SpannableString(story.getText());
// ...
String additionalStoryText = " " + "<b>" + field[y] + "</b>" + " ";
additionalStoryText.replaceAll("\n", "<br />"); // assuming you only want this for the appended text.
spannedStoryText = new SpannableString(TextUtils.concat(spannedStoryText, Html.fromHtml(additonalStoryText)));
story.setText(spannedStoryText);
```

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thank you very much, I can't wait to get enough reputation to upvote so I can upvote people like you! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 storyText = storyText + " " + "<b>" + field[y] + "</b>" + " ";
                        storyText.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
                        spanned = Html.fromHtml(storyText);
                        story.setText(spanned);
```

These lines of code make the text that you had on your `TextView` normal and the new text bold, because you are just using `<b>` and `</b>` tags after `storyText` . That is why only the new text is bold and the old one stays regular.

Change your code to:

```
 storyText = "<b>" + storyText + "</b> "+ " " + "<b>" + field[y] + "</b>" + " ";
                        storyText.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
                        spanned = Html.fromHtml(storyText);
                        story.setText(spanned);
```

Comment: Some of my text is regular and some of it is bold. This new method makes all my text bold when I only need the strings (or fields) from the alert dialog bolded. Thank you for the help, I feel like we are getting closer! @joao2fast4u